# unbrick a brick zte Axon Mini 7

Tags: unbricking, zte

The phone died suddenly, no lights, no beeps, no logos, no charging - bricked completely. Any ideas or strategies that might unbrick it?

I know it is out of its prime days but elegant and reasonably sized.

Already tried

- left charging overnight
- click vol up down in the same time, vol down and start in the same time
- tried other cables/outlets/chargers

UPDATE: I was able to produce solid red dot with by pressing first vol up and down and then start. I found an recipe on internet, but it had dead link to miflash tool, I can find alternative miflash download  with google search though not sure which version is more legit/efficient

UPDATE 2: somehow was able to reboot, seems to work, yet is suspiciously hot, not sure may be I should uninstall some apps or reset to factory